# Replace newlines with \n and tabs with \t

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have to Convert java source code from next-line curly-brace style to the end-of-line curly-brace style.

I found a way to do this with formatted String (with \n and \t) and it works perfectly, but I have to read the source code from File.

The following code

#### Next-Line Brace Style Code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Some statements
    }
}
```

#### should be converted to:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Some statements
    }
}
```

---

Now, the way I approached this, is as follow:

The mentioned code with \n and \t is as follow (we name this **String s2**)

```
public class Test\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "\tpublic static void main(String[] args)\n" +
                "\t{\n" +
                "\t\t// Some statements\n" +
                "\t}\n" +
                "}\n
```

I then wrote the following code, to convert it to end-of-line style.

```
s2 = s2.replaceAll("\\t\\{", "{");
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s2);

for (int i = 0; i < stringBuilder.length(); i++) {
    if (stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '{') {
        stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(i);
        stringBuilder.insert(i - 1, " {");
    }
}
```

This works as far as I checked.

---

Now the actual problem;

When I read from the file, the source code doesn't have any \t and \n and I would like to convert the source code to a string, which like above string (s2) has \t and \n.

---

Just to clarify, I use the following method to read from input:

```
File sourceFile = new File("oldFormattedSourceCode.txt");
String oldFormatString = "";
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(sourceFile);) {
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        oldFormatString += input.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Old Format String is: " + oldFormatString.toString());
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.print(ex.getMessage());

}
```

Which gives me the following output

```
Old Format String is: public class Test{    public static void main(String[] args)    {        // Some statements    }}
```

And this String is no use to me because it doesn't have \n and \t, which the code I wrote depends on these.

Please suggest.

Comment: `oldFormatString += input.nextLine();` after this, you should manually add the new line character. Since you're reading line by line, you read one line, append the next line, without the newline character, you are getting such an output. the `nextLine()` function gives you the line without the new line character.

Comment: wow, that was fast :D, Thanks a lot. I added `oldFormatString += "\n";` and the string looks exactly like the original string. which is great. but unfortunately I need the `\t` characters too, because this line `s2.replaceAll("\\t\\{", "{");` need `\t` char to work. Thanks for help.

Comment: aren't you using any IDE like eclipse, netbeans or intellij? these IDEs can do this formatting for you.

Comment: I'am using IntelliJ IDEA. and exactly what you have said. The String mentioned above (the 3rd code-block) is formatted by IntelliJ IDEA. But how can I accomplish this formatted String (how did IntelliJ do it)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Scanner` to read your file, use a `FileReader`

```
try (FileReader input = new FileReader(sourceFile);) {
    int i = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while ((i=input.read())!=-1) {
        sb.append((char)i);
    }
    oldFormatString = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("Old Format String is: " + oldFormatString.toString());
} catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
    System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
}
```

You can read individual characters if you use a `FileReader`, hence you wont miss any characters.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just `StringBuilder` and check input file line by line:

```
private static String convert(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();

            if ("{".equals(line.trim()))
                buf.append(" {").append(lineSeparator);
            else {
                if (buf.length() > 0)
                    buf.append(lineSeparator);

                buf.append(line);
            }
        }

        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```